# Textmate, How do I limit the folders TODO bundle searches when it launches?

Tags: textmate, textmatebundles, todo

I like the TODO bundle in textmate. 
When I launch it however, it searches what seems like my entire drive. 
Is there a way I can tell it to just search, for example, my projects folder?
Or better yet, the folder of the project that is currently open?

This article, [Textmate: Taming TODOs and FIXMEs,](http://mdeering.com/posts/004-get-your-textmate-todos-and-fixmes-under-control) shows you how to make it ignore a folder,

I was wondering if there was a way to set a target folder for todo to scan?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In textmate2 you can set the **TM_TODO_IGNORE** variable in **.tm_properties**, nice to set TODO exceptions on a project basis. It should be a regular expression. Example:

TM_TODO_IGNORE = '/(disabled(-src)?|onig-.*|build|cache|CxxTest|(FScript|BWToolkitFramework).framework)/'

It is also possible to set **TM_TODO_IGNORE** in Preferences > Variables, same regex.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the todo bundle from Stanley Rost - last modified on Jan 06, 2010 and installed thanks to the great GetBundles bundle.

If nothing is selected in the Project Panel, TODO looks in the project for; if folders or files are selected in the Project Panel then TODO looks only in they for. Note that there is a filter panel in the TODO list window too.

HTH

Antoine